# Не компилируются файлы java на windows xp

Tags: eclipse, компиляция, установка, java

Примерно год назад установил jdk с целью программирования на языке java. Тогда всё отлично работало, но вот недавно я решил возобновить изучение языка.

Закачал Eclipse (раньше пользовался IntelliJ Idea) и с огорчением заметил, что в разделе Warnings написано `Build path specifies execution enviorment JavaSE-1.7. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are stricktly compatible with this enviorment`.

Естественно, программа не компилировалась. Тогда я переустановил jdk в надежде, что может хоть так все заработает. В панели управления я указал `Path` значение `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin` и `JAVA_HOME` — `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121`, но всё равно ничего не работало. Командная строка ПРАВИЛЬНО реагирует на команду `java`, но команду `javac` просто не видит и выдает ошибку. Подскажите пожалуйста, где я ошибся? Как заставить джаву работать? У меня windows xp.

Comment: Сейчас мало кто утруждает себя тестированием софта на совместомость с xp. Даже на висту смотрят пренебрежительно. Я бы попробовал ещё раз с idea, может оно там заработает.

Comment: @KoVadim, я попробовал сделать то же самое на windows 7, но тоже не получилось